# Problem with <form> tag in the view source code in a browser

Tags: html, laravel, forms

I have this application and have the forms on it. As I check in the source code in the browser I've seen that my form tag is colored red. I think this means that something has wrong on it. But when I click on the button into my form it is not working.

Below here is the screen shot image.[image]

Can someone help me figured this thing out? my structure in adding a form tag into my views is really okay. Submit button not working because of this.

Any help is much appreciated. TIA

My code for view

```
 <table width="800" class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable"  cellspacing="0">
                                             <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>Invoice #</th>
                                                <th>Whole Lechon 500/KL</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>Amount</th>
                                                <th>Paid Amount</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <th>Collection Date</th>
                                                <th>Cheque Number</th>
                                                <th>Cheque Amount</th>
                                                <th>OR Number</th>
                                                <th>Payment Method</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                               </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                            <tbody>
                                                 @foreach($sAccounts as $sAccount)
                                                <form action="{{ action('LoloPinoyLechonDeCebuController@sAccountUpdate', $sAccount['id']) }}" method="post">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                         {{csrf_field()}}
                                                       <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                                                       <p style="width: 110px;">{{ $sAccount['transaction_date']}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                      <p style="width: 110px;">{{ $sAccount['invoice_number'] }}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                        <p style="width: 110px;">{{ $sAccount['whole_lechon']}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                       <p style="width: 300px;">{{ $sAccount['description']}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="bg-danger" style="color:white;">
                                                       <p ><?php echo number_format($sAccount['amount'], 2); ?></p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input style="width: 100px;" type="text" name="paidAmount" class="form-control"  />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="25%">
                                                       <input style="width:110px;" type="text" name="status" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                         <input type="text" name="collectionDat" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                         <input style="width: 110px;" type="text" name="chequeNumber" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                         <input style="width: 110px;"  type="text" name="chequeAmount" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input style="width: 110px;"  type="text" name="orNumber" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                         <select style="width: 160px;" class="form-control" name="paymentMethod">
                                                            <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
                                                            <option value="CHEQUE">CHEQUE</option>
                                                            <option value="ACCOUNT">ACCOUNT</option>
                                                       </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                           <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Paid" style="width: 100px;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </form>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </tbody>

                                         </table>
```

Comment: Can you show your code for view?

Comment: why the end of `form` tag has gone up.

Comment: @HarpalSingh there i add the source code. i update it